# When assemby stack push and pop

Tags: assembly, stack

Some time ago (2-3 years) in my university we were programming MC68HC11 micro controller and our lecturer described us that the stack is some part of the memory which have this functionalities:

- store the state of an interrupted program
- store the callback address when transition to a subprogram
- the stack is also available for the programmer needs

I have never understood how it is possible to transit to a subprogram. Actually I know there is PC (program counter) which is pointing the current byte from the current executing program, i.e. points to where the executing of the program is reached. Can someone give example when the stack will pull and when will pop something (maybe JMP above the code, but I don't think it will do it). Is stack pulls and pops automatically performed(excluding programmers needs)? Do I need to write two programs in the memory and then call the one from the another to perform automatic stack pull?

**unnecessarily right now:**

I am actually trying to understand the assembly stack, because I want to make comparison with C and C++ stack and the heap and be able to master so called "stack trace debugging", but this will be in next thread, that is for now.

Comment: `jmp` doesn't use the stack. Generally speaking calling another subroutine (not another program) will push the return address on the stack, and returning from the subroutine will pop and use that. Details for your particular architecture can be found in the documentation.

Comment: What is subroutin in context of assembly? If it was C - maybe this can be function, but here we have program which starts and ends. I am not asking about this architecture, I ask teoretically when it will do it. The example can be given in any architecture - there are documentations with the instructions set.

Comment: The cpu doesn't care. You decide what's a function/procedure. If you use the appropriate call instruction, the cpu will just push the return address and do a jump. It doesn't check anything. Note that some architectures don't use the stack automatically, others don't even have a hardware stack.

Comment: OK I understood. The stack is mean to make functions in assembly, In C you don't care what the stack is doing. You just write function and it all happens automaticly. The last think I wonder is - the stack stores only addresses or it can store other data and if it can - why someone would want to store something different like it will be on the top of the stack and will mess up all callback things?

Comment: Yes it can store other things, it's typically used for local variables which should be destroyed before the function returns. That way it won't mess up the return addresses.

Comment: Very nice. Now I begin to understand C language in depth, but I wonder when you are returning to main reoutine (for example using some instruction like `ret`), or you are poping the callback address - how the program understand which is address and which is local variable, i.e. if on the top of the stack we have - local var, local var, local var, call back addres ... how when our subroutine reach `ret` it will destroy all local vars. I can think of - we have to pop them mannualy from the stack, so we have-push three local vars in the start and in the end pop them and then `ret`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you (or the compiler) must make sure the proper amount of locals are removed before returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In x86:

- `push rax` decrements the stack pointer, then stores the value at the location now pointed to by the stack pointer.
- `pop  rax` does the opposite: equivalent to `mov rax, [rsp]` / `add rsp, 8`.

Call pushes the address of the following instruction, and then jumps to the target.  If you're curious about x86 in any more detail, see the links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

The stack pointer starts out pointing at the top of a block of memory allocated for use as a stack.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack.  There might be better links for an intro to how computers use "the" stack (as opposed to custom stack data structures), but that one looks ok.

Comment: Do that mean I can call subroutine two ways - with the use of `call` (more automatic) or with the use of `push` and `jmp`(less automatic)? Do the stack stores only addresses, or I can store some custom value in it and why I would want to do it?

Comment: Yes you can simulate `call` by using `push` + `jmp`.

Comment: @nicksona: You can use the stack for temporary storage.  Doing that allows you to write recursive / thread-safe functions, compared to using static storage where multiple simultaneous invocations of a function would step on each other.  It's also used for passing function parameters, beyond the number that fit in registers.

Answer (score 2):

`call` and the interrupts push PC in the stack and `ret` and `iret` pop PC back again automatically on common CPUs. thats all.

Comment: Correct me if I am mistaking - I understood in assembly it seems you must specify the address where your function begin and use for example the `call` instruction in x86 to push to the stack the next instruction and then `jmp` to go to the start of your subroutine(function) and then use `ret` to pop the stack address and continue execution of main function.

Comment: call = push PC, jmp addr